# How to know what is your command options in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have learned a lot in the past week. One thing I couldn't figure it out. is where to look to find proper documentation for command and module. to be more specific I am using `pxssh` module for remote session control. every hour, I found something new that this module can do

```
s= pxssh.pxssh()
s.before
s.prompt
s.login
s.sendline
.
.
.
```

I don't know what else, but I am sure there is more. so for this module in specific and for all module and command in general. Where to find all the possible command options?

By the way is there any way I can read what is in the session and print it on the screen?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: install `ipython`; `ipython` shell can do tab completion out of box for these. You can also try the `help` function, a.k.a `help(pxssh)` or `help(pxssh.pxssh)`.

Comment: google is also a very good place to look for documentation ;P

Comment: how can I install the ipython?

Answer (score 1):

Use `help()`.

For example `help(list)` gives:

```
class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
 |
 |  __contains__(...)
 |      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
 |
 |  __delitem__(...)
 |      x.__delitem__(y) <==> del x[y]
 |
 |  __delslice__(...)
 |      x.__delslice__(i, j) <==> del x[i:j]
 |
 |      Use of negative indices is not supported.
 |
 |  __eq__(...)
 |      x.__eq__(y) <==> x==y
 |
 |  __ge__(...)
 |      x.__ge__(y) <==> x>=y
 |
 |  __getattribute__(...)
 |      x.__getattribute__('name') <==> x.name
 |
 |  __getitem__(...)
 |      x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]
 |
 |  __getslice__(...)
 |      x.__getslice__(i, j) <==> x[i:j]
 |
 |      Use of negative indices is not supported.
 |
 |  __gt__(...)
 |      x.__gt__(y) <==> x>y
 |
 |  __iadd__(...)
 |      x.__iadd__(y) <==> x+=y
 |
 |  __imul__(...)
 |      x.__imul__(y) <==> x*=y
 |
 |  __init__(...)
 |      x.__init__(...) initializes x; see help(type(x)) for signature
 |
 |  __iter__(...)
 |      x.__iter__() <==> iter(x)
 |
 |  __le__(...)
 |      x.__le__(y) <==> x<=y
 |
 |  __len__(...)
 |      x.__len__() <==> len(x)
 |
 |  __lt__(...)
 |      x.__lt__(y) <==> x<y
 |
 |  __mul__(...)
 |      x.__mul__(n) <==> x*n
 |
 |  __ne__(...)
 |      x.__ne__(y) <==> x!=y
 |
 |  __repr__(...)
 |      x.__repr__() <==> repr(x)
 |
 |  __reversed__(...)
 |      L.__reversed__() -- return a reverse iterator over the list
 |
 |  __rmul__(...)
 |      x.__rmul__(n) <==> n*x
 |
 |  __setitem__(...)
 |      x.__setitem__(i, y) <==> x[i]=y
 |
 |  __setslice__(...)
 |      x.__setslice__(i, j, y) <==> x[i:j]=y
 |
 |      Use  of negative indices is not supported.
 |
 |  __sizeof__(...)
 |      L.__sizeof__() -- size of L in memory, in bytes
 |
 |  append(...)
 |      L.append(object) -- append object to end
 |
 |  count(...)
 |      L.count(value) -> integer -- return number of occurrences of value
 |
 |  extend(...)
 |      L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
 |
 |  index(...)
 |      L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
 |      Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
 |
 |  insert(...)
 |      L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index
 |
 |  pop(...)
 |      L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
 |      Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
 |
 |  remove(...)
 |      L.remove(value) -- remove first occurrence of value.
 |      Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
 |
 |  reverse(...)
 |      L.reverse() -- reverse *IN PLACE*
 |
 |  sort(...)
 |      L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
 |      cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |
 |  __hash__ = None
 |
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

Further, if you're already familiar with an object and just forget a name, you can use `dir()` to list the attributes:

```
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Comment: I am writing all my code in linux environment and running it as script from linux terminal. therefore what command line environment is best to do that. Also how can I install ipython??